# matrix of connection

Tags: dip, jumper

I'm looking for a component that can connect 1:1 4 input to 4 output

```
1----|-|-|-|-
2----|-|-|-|-
3----|-|-|-|-
4----|-|-|-|-
     | | | |    
     A B C D
```

My purpose is to map 1-c,2-b,3-a,4-d and so on but I never map the same pin to 2 out

```
1----|-|-X-|-
2----|-X-|-|-
3----X-|-|-|-
4----|-|-|-X-
     | | | |    
     A B C D
```

Actually I use jumper or dip switch, so I can create 4x4, 8x8 and so on. It is simple to use, passive but it needs a lot of space. So I ask: Is something better?

- Passive (no +Vcc)
- Active (some impressive circuit that need Power Supply)

@Downvoters ... Explain

Comment: What sort of signals (analogue or digital)? How are the connections re-configured, and how often?

Comment: @pjc50 audio signals from rj11

Comment: @FakeName USB like cold be a good idea today is wide used but if it's not enough any type of power supply could be used.

Answer (score 2):

Use latching relays. These 1) pass analog signals, unlike a CPLD and 2) don't require power to stay in a state. That's the "latching" part.

This was written before we knew they were analog:

If digital signaling, you can use PALs, GALs, or CPLDs.
Theses are programmable logical units that can be used to perform your user defined function.
Low gate count devices are quite inexpensive (~1$).

Comment: CPLD's might be the best choice since PALs and GALs are pretty old and you might have trouble getting them. Also cheap CPLD evaluation boards are available.

Comment: @BrianCarlton I don't know until now the existence of CPLD thanks

Answer (score 1):

You say above that you are switching audio lines. There are a number of analog switch ics on the market but most of them seem to be in the form of SPDT or DPDT switches. Eg: (one input to two specific outputs) * 2 or * 4.

What you might be looking for is a *crosspoint* switch. Example: "MT8806A 8x4 Analog Switch IC" (Futurlec have those). Analog Devices also have these type but they are very high speed switches and are probably expensive. Take a look at the Mitel chip above and see if it's what you want.

While looking I came across http://www.engadget.com/2007/03/13/how-to-make-a-solid-state-a-v-switcher/ which is interesting even if it's not what you seem to want.

Aside: Back in the day I remember people using small EPROMs to perform the function of a CPLD. Address lines in, data out. But that's pretty hackish. There are digital matrix ics to do switching too, assuming you're building a telephone exchange!